# Python and GNU Portable Threads

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to build Python with [GNU Portable Threads](http://www.gnu.org/software/pth/pth.html)?
Are there any Pth libraries for Python?

Comment: http://blogger.popcnt.org/2007/10/gnu-pth-instead-of-pthread-hardcore.html

Comment: @LennartRegebro: A custom patch for 2.5.1? I'm using 3.2 or 3.3... I hoped there is a `configure` switch.

Comment: It's a patch for the build configuration, which should be fairly simple to adapt to 3.2 or 3.3. However, further checking shows that the actual Patch file is no longer in existence... The blog does tell you what the problem is: pth is API-compatible with pthread, the trick is in to make the Python build use pth instead of pthread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be well supported anymore, probably because native threading has become so ubiquitous. A few custom patches exist for older versions of Python. Pth also provides instructions for how to dupe builds into using it for threading calls.